# How to make UserControl add attachments

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to make user control in Windows application c#

I need make attachments files in form but I need use an user control when click
button browse and choose the files or image add user control in form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button on the form and use [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like that:

```
private void buttonGetFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Text files | *.txt"; // file types, that will be allowed to upload
    dialog.Multiselect = false; // allow/deny user to upload more than one file at a time
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // if user clicked OK
    {
        String path = dialog.FileName; // get name of file
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), new UTF8Encoding())) // do anything you want, e.g. read it
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```